# Unexpected use of ( batch file

Tags: batch-file

In the following code I want to terminate `ABClient.exe` and `ABClientMonitor.exe` if it is found running. However when trying to run the code I get a `Unexpected use of (` error

Code:

```
@echo off
color 0b
:loop
tasklist | find /i "ABClient.exe" > nul
set processFound1=%errorlevel%
tasklist | find /i "ABClientMonitor.exe" > nul
set processFound2=%errorlevel%
if %processFound1% == 0 (
    echo ABClient has been detected. Terminating...
    taskkill /f /im "ABClient.exe" > nul
    set process1lvl=%errorlevel%
    if %process1lvl% == 0 (
        echo ABClient has been terminated successfully!
        goto loop2
    ) ELSE (
        echo Failed to terminate ABClient!
        goto loop2
    )
)
:loop2
if %processFound2% == 0 (
    echo ABClientMonitor has been detected. Terminating...
    taskkill /f /im "ABClientMonitor.exe" > nul
    set process2lvl=%errorlevel%
    if %process2lvl% == 0 (
        echo ABClientMonitor has been terminated successfully!
        goto loop
    ) ELSE (
        echo Failed to terminate ABClientMonitor!
    goto loop
    )
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables that are declared inside of parentheses need to be called with delayed expansion, otherwise they effectively don't exist. In this case, because of the position of the `%process1lvl%` and `%process2lvl%` variables, your inner `if` statements evaluate to `if == 0 (`, which causes a syntax error.

To correct this, add the line `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to the start of your script and replace `%process1lvl%` with `!process1lvl!` and replace `%process2lvl%` with `!process2lvl!`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
color 0b
:loop
tasklist | find /i "ABClient.exe" > nul
set processFound1=%errorlevel%
tasklist | find /i "ABClientMonitor.exe" > nul
set processFound2=%errorlevel%
if %processFound1% == 0 (
    echo ABClient has been detected. Terminating...
    taskkill /f /im "ABClient.exe" > nul
    set process1lvl=!errorlevel!
    if !process1lvl! == 0 (
        echo ABClient has been terminated successfully!
        goto loop2
    ) ELSE (
        echo Failed to terminate ABClient!
        goto loop2
    )
)
:loop2
if %processFound2% == 0 (
    echo ABClientMonitor has been detected. Terminating...
    taskkill /f /im "ABClientMonitor.exe" > nul
    set process2lvl=!errorlevel!
    if !process2lvl! == 0 (
        echo ABClientMonitor has been terminated successfully!
        goto loop
    ) ELSE (
        echo Failed to terminate ABClientMonitor!
    goto loop
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Just wondering, what would I do if a variable was in a parentheses - inside of a parentheses. Would it still be !variable!?

Comment: Yes, any time a variable is within at least one set of parentheses, you need delayed expansion, otherwise the value of the variable will not update.